# Unusual javascript object notation

Tags: javascript, object, auth0

What does `_raw`, `_json` and `...userProfile` mean as used in the below code  ? This is from the `auth0` example. Thank you!

```
router.get('/user', secured(), function (req, res, next)
{
    const { _raw, _json, ...userProfile } = req.user;
    console.log ('rec user ', req.user);
    //console.log ('user profile ', userProfile);
    res.render('user', {
        userProfile: JSON.stringify(userProfile, null, 2),
        title: 'Profile page'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That notation is called **[Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**. Basically, `req.user` is an `object` with keys `_raw`, `_json` and other keys. With that syntax, you are reading directly the properties `_raw` and `_json` of the object and the rest of the object is saved into the `userProfile` variable. For that part, the **[Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** is used.

## Demo Example:

```js
const req = {
    user: {
      _raw: "raw",
      _json: "json",
      other1: "other1",
      other2: "other2"
    } 
};

const { _raw, _json, ...userProfile } = req.user;
console.log("_raw is: ", _raw);
console.log("_json is: ", _json);
console.log("userProfile is: ", userProfile);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```